# Default output when h:message is empty

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I'm looking for a way to achieve the following switch in JSF:

```
 ...
 <div>
   if empty(<h:message for="x">)
     <h:outputText value="default value" />
   else
     <h:message for="x" />
   endif
 </div>
 ....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's only possible on `h:messages`, not on a particular `h:message`. Are you certain that you need it for that? What would you like to show then? What's the functional requirement? Maybe there are better ways.

Comment: I'd like to (re)show a validation message based on the content of an inputfield. If (after a blur event) the content of a textfield is considered valid a message like "OK" should be displayed, if the content is invalid, the validation error should be displayed.

Comment: I get what you mean. JSF however doesn't support standard facilities for that. It may get pretty complicated. By the way, to notify others about comment replies in a post which are not their own, use `@nickname`. See also [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable with a little help of a [`PhaseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html).

Here's how the view look like, not shocking, just a `<f:ajax>` on every input component which hooks on `blur` event and thus immediately re-renders the message component when the input field loses focus.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Stackoverflow question 4313917</title>
        <style>.info { color: green; } .error { color: red; }</style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel for="input1">Input 1</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="input1" value="#{bean.input1}" required="true">
                    <f:ajax event="blur" render="input1message" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message id="input1message" for="input1" infoClass="info" errorClass="error" />

                <h:outputLabel for="input2">Input 2</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="input2" value="#{bean.input2}" required="true">
                    <f:ajax event="blur" render="input2message" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message id="input2message" for="input2" infoClass="info" errorClass="error" />

                <h:outputLabel for="input3">Input 3</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="input3" value="#{bean.input3}" required="true">
                    <f:ajax event="blur" render="input3message" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message id="input3message" for="input3" infoClass="info" errorClass="error" />

                <h:panelGroup />
                <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
                <h:panelGroup />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>  
</html>
```

Bean speaks for itself: 3 properties `input1`, `input2` and `input3` and a `void submit()` method. Just let your IDE autogenerate the boilerplate.

Here's the `PhaseListener`:

```
package com.example;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;

public class MessagePhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
        if (facesContext.isPostback()) {
            UIViewRoot viewRoot = facesContext.getViewRoot();
            for (String clientId : facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().keySet()) {
                UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent(clientId);
                if (component instanceof UIInput && !facesContext.getMessages(clientId).hasNext()) {
                    facesContext.addMessage(clientId, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "OK!", null));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // NOOP. It's too late anyway.
    }

}
```

Register it as follows in `faces-config.xml` (no, unfortunately, there are no JSF 2.0 annotations for phaselisteners).

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.example.MessagePhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

You may want to parameterize the "OK!" message in the phaselistener.

Comment: how do you specify that this phaseListener is applied to a specific page ?

Comment: HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) phaseEvent.getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getRequest();request.getRequestURI().startWith or .endsWidth or .equals