# Understanding the PhaseListener.getPhaseId

Tags: jsf, phaselistener

HI,

I need clarification on implementing the *PhaseListener* class. The following is the two different overriding implementation for the *PhaseListener.getPhaseId*

```
@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {       
    return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {       
    return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
}
```

What could be the significant difference in those two implementations?. What will be the impact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the [`PhaseListener#getPhaseId()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html#getPhaseId%28%29) javadoc, this indicates for which [`PhaseId`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html) the current [`PhaseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) implementation should execute the implemented [`beforePhase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html#beforePhase%28javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent%29) and [`afterPhase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html#afterPhase%28javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent%29) methods. In the first example, they will be executed on *any* phase and in the second example, they will be executed in the [`RESTORE_VIEW`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html#RESTORE_VIEW) phase only (which is the firstmost phase of the JSF lifecycle).

Comment: So that means it will not affect the jsf phases lifecycle correct? It is just for the PhaseListener implementation.

Comment: No. Unless you write code inside `beforePhase()` or `afterPhase()` which alters the lifecyle :) The `PhaseListener` is there just to be able to run some code on specific phases of the JSF lifecycle, for *every* HTTP request/response. It's like a servlet `Filter`, but then one which is able to grab the `FacesContext` and execute during specific phases only. There are not so many use cases though. More than often a plain managed bean or even a `Filter` is sufficient. You can at least find a good real world example in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/set-focus-in-jsf.html).

Comment: Another one comes to mind, check my answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313917/default-output-when-hmessage-is-empty). This one puts "OK" success message for every field which passed validation. A bit an edge case, but actually also a good demonstration of what a `PhaseListener` can be used for.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for those explanations, however is it possible to specify only some Phases and not all of them ?